# xdebug does not show the content of array?

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using vim and xdebug to debug my php program, when I press F12 to get an array value,
the result is just (array). How to show the content of the array?

$loadedModels = self::$_loadedModelFiles;

When the cursor is on $loadedModels, and I press F12 ,
the result is as bellow:

/*{{{1*/ => property_get: loadedModels

$command = 'property_get';

```
  $loadedModels = (array)
```

/*}}}1*/

this is my xdebug config:

```
Directive Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace On On
xdebug.collect_assignments Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On On
xdebug.collect_params 4 4
xdebug.collect_return Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars On On
xdebug.default_enable On On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE no value no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value no value
xdebug.dump.FILES no value no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value no value
xdebug.dump.POST no value no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER no value no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value no value
xdebug.dump_globals On On
xdebug.dump_once On On
xdebug.dump_undefined Off Off
xdebug.extended_info On On
xdebug.file_link_format no value no value
xdebug.idekey root no value
xdebug.manual_url http://www.php.net http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level 100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump On On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir /tmp /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart On On
xdebug.remote_connect_back Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time 3600 3600
xdebug.remote_enable On On
xdebug.remote_handler dbgp dbgp
xdebug.remote_host localhost localhost
xdebug.remote_log no value no value
xdebug.remote_mode req req
xdebug.remote_port 9000 9000
xdebug.scream Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars On On
xdebug.show_mem_delta Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0 0
xdebug.trace_options 0 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name %H %H
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth 10 10
```

Comment: You are leaving out important details. Xdebug is a server-side extension, pressing F12 can not have any effect on it. You probably are using some kind of IDE where this key works and you should give the name of that IDE if you want to get any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($loadedModels);
```