# xdebug vim plugin doesn't show variable values (php)

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

vim version 7.2.330

xdebug vim plugin version 1.1.1 (downloaded from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1929)

PHP 5.3.2

Apache/2.2.14

Xdebug v2.0.5

I have these options in my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file

```
[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000

; General
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.collect_includes=on
xdebug.collect_params=off
xdebug.collect_return=off
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.manual_url=http://www.php.net
xdebug.show_local_vars=0 (tried with 1, same result)
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level=100
;xdebug.idekey=

; Trace options
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_output_name=crc32

; Profiling
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name=crc32
```

When I press F12 to show variable content, instead of showing it like for example on this image http://2bits.com/sites/2bits.com/files/vim-debug-displaying-variables.png (top right window) I get this `/*{{{1*/ => property_get: file` when I press F12 on `$file` var.

I also tried the version that is attached to this article
http://2bits.com/articles/using-vim-and-xdebug-dbgp-for-debugging-drupal-or-any-php-application.html

Same result.

I also found almost the same unanswered question here [xdebug does not show the content of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182225/xdebug-does-not-show-the-content-of-array)

Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: screenshot: http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/2637/screenshot3cf.png

Comment: Python version 2.6.5 (used by vim plugin)

Comment: in vim i have +signs and +python

Comment: Do other xdebug-vim features work, such as stepping through code (step-in, step-over, etcetera)?

Comment: yes, everything works except this variable thingy

Answer (score 1):

Edit debugger.vim file (~/.vim/plugin/debugger.vim) and find a line similar to

```
let g:debuggerMaxDepth = 1
```

increase the depth varibale to a reasonable amount (5 should be enough)
save and restart vim.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your xdebug question, but for simple variable contents checking I found [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) quite useful.