# xDebug with Vim

Tags: php, vim, xdebug

Just started messing around with xDebug a bit. So i'm trying to learn the debugger. I got Vim 7.2 and xDebug 2.1.0 installed. I have installed the debugger plugin from [this page](http://2bits.com/articles/using-vim-and-xdebug-dbgp-for-debugging-drupal-or-any-php-application.html). I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly but I try to go to `line 8` on the `$b` and pressed `<F12>` although all I'm getting is `/*{{{1*/ => property_get: b`. Any ideas?

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467673/xdebug-vim-plugin-doesnt-show-variable-values-php) but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$b` is currently undefined. Try pressing `<F12>` only after the line on which it is defined. You can do that by navigating to the variable with `hjkl` just as you do outside xdebug.

Note that you can also press `<F11>` to show the value of all variables defined.